# How to know when an email is sent with Android Gmail app and who is it sent to?

Tags: android, email, vpn

I'm interested on building an app that knows when an email is sent with Android's Gmail app and to who is sent.

Since there is no plugin API for the Android Gmail app the only method I've found to do this is capturing outgoing packets that use the SMTP protocol. Using this method will I be able to identify emails and read their destinatary? Or will the destinatary be encrypted under SSL?

Are there other ways to do this?

Comment: "Or will the destinatary be encrypted under SSL?" -- I sure hope so.

Comment: This would be viewed by most people as malware, so hopefully it is not possible!

Comment: I don't want to do anything without the user permission and even if I wanted when you listen for packets on Android the user sees a gigantic persistent message notifying the traffic is being filtered.

Comment: @CommonsWare Android offers a class to access the phone's certificate's so even if the destinatary is encrypted one could in the end decrypt the packet. I've seem some basic packet filtering apps that do it without rooting the phone.

Answer (score 0):

To know whether the Gmail app encrypts the destination you can set up a wireless access point on your local machine and connect to it on your device. [Here](http://raspberrypihq.com/how-to-turn-a-raspberry-pi-into-a-wifi-router/) is a tutorial on how to do that with a RaspberryPi. Once your smartphone uses that access point to connect to the internet you can use a sniffer like [Wireshark](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wireshark/) to analyse the traffic.

Alternatively if your device is rooted you can use [tPacketCapture](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.taosoftware.android.packetcapture&hl=en) to sniff your traffic.

I haven't checked but it will most likely be encrypted.

Capturing all outgoing packages with an app would be a major security problem and is thus not possible on Android unless your application has root access. So you probably won't be able to achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: thanks, I'll try it. Do you know any other way of knowing when an email leaves the phone?